# Wanting to make an Xposed module

Tags: xposed, xposed-framework

So I'm wanting to make an xposed module but cannot find any good video tutorials out there let alone an updated one also I know C# Decently and hardly any Java... Any help to help me get started would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need Java to create any Xposed modules. Android itself is based on (primarily) Java, so you will need Java knowledge to make Xposed modules.

That said, C# and Java are extremely similar languages, and you can quickly pick up the other if you know one.

As for Tutorials, Rovo89 (the creator of Xposed) has a simple tutorial here at https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial. This tutorial is almost completely upto-date, and you can use this to create your first module.

You will find another detailed tutorial here - https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2709324. Keep in mind that this link is very old, so wherever there are any conflicts, go by Rovo89's tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the beginner tutorial mentioned by Akhil, you will want to look at the API docs http://api.xposed.info/reference/packages.html and read through source code of some huge modules like GravityBox to get an idea of how the Framework is used. For teaching purpose mod some app which is open source and then move on to closed source app by reverse engineering them. For reverse engineering I use ByteCodeViewer.